# Google calendar: how to access it on android

Tags: java, android, api, calendar

What would be the best way to acces the google calendar on android right now?

I found the following ways:

[google-api-java-client](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-v2-atom-android-sample/instructions.html?r=default) - It's only an alpha. Authenticating, getting calendar list works, but updating calendar crashes in sample. +no documentation and bad sample codes anyway.

[hackity hack reverse engeneering](http://www.developer.com/ws/article.php/3850276/Working-with-the-Android-Calendar.htm) - Sounds bad, also, (propably) not futureproof.

[Google data api](http://code.google.com/intl/hu-HU/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_java.html) - As far as I know, it does not support/work on android.

Are there any alternatives that I have missed? Are there any working examples out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently used [SignPost](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/) for this. It handles OAuth, and you can use it to sign your HTTP requests to get or post data to your calendars. I had trouble getting Google's Java API to work with Android since I think it relies on Java APIs that are not necessarily present in Android.

To make your requests, you can refer to this page: http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html

Comment: I'll give SignPost a try, but I really wanted that "just click here to accept" user experience with the already available google apis. Every other way the user has to enter his/her credentials right?

Comment: Could you provide some examples maybe? I'm kinda stuck.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer
I have all necessery jars..

Comment: Here's an example using Twitter: http://dev.bostone.us/2009/07/16/android-oauth-twitter-updates/. The same process applies to GCal. As for your exception, SignPost has a dependency on Apache Commons Codec (http://commons.apache.org/codec/). Download 1.3 or greater and add it to your project and it should fix your error.

Comment: I found that tutorial, but it still doesn't work.
I tried a fresh commons jar, CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer cannot be resolved.

Comment: Whoops, I can't read. I think you need to download the signpost-commonshttp jar from here: http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/downloads/list. It should have the CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer class.

Comment: You can read allright, so do I ;)
Already tried several variations(that signpost-commons jar too), the best I could acchive, was crash in runtime.
CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer("xyz", "lol");
this throws an exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer

Comment: Weird... the only jars I have added in my project are commons-lang3-3.0-beta, signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1, and signpost-core-1.2.1.1. Maybe try cleaning and rebuilding your project?

Comment: I have:
signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar
signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar
tried adding(I don't know why this should be needed): commons-lang3-3.0-beta.jar
Tried cleaning too several times, no change.
I'm gona sleep on this one, maybe tomorrow it will work ;)

Comment: The Getting Started page (http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/wiki/GettingStarted) says commons-lang is needed if you are manually adding the jars, ie. not straight up working with the source. What does your #import look like for the "missing" class?

Comment: These are my imports for the whole class:
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import oauth.signpost.OAuth;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthProvider;

Comment: That all looks good. I put my three jars in my Dropbox, see if they work for you.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9374853/SignPostLibs/commons-lang3-3.0-beta.jar
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9374853/SignPostLibs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9374853/SignPostLibs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar

Comment: Lol. These are identical to the ones that I have, and they work. I have no idea what went wrong, maybe I downloaded corrupted files (several times?!). Thank you.

Comment: Well I really really wanted to use the google-api-java-client, but so far it doesn't work for me. Maybe after it leaves alpha state it will be the good choice for android, but right now, big thumbs up for SignPost.

Comment: I tried using google-api-java-client, but if I remember correctly it has dependencies that aren't present in Android, at least yet. Chalk it up to keeping the system image as small as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Data API Developer's Guide: Java](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_java.html)? You can also work directly with [HTTP request/response](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html), if things you want/need aren't supported in the Java API.

I haven't personally used the Java API, but I have worked directly with HTTP, and found it to be pretty straightforward.

Comment: As far as I know android does not work well with the Gdata api, that's why I'm trying to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a well known issue, but not so well clear yet. Looking at all the questions and answer provided it seems that you have two options:

- Use the hacks you were refering in your answer (not suggested at all, because as you said there is no guarantee that the same trick will work in future). Some updates have been made in order to make it works even under froyo, see [here](http://www.andreabaccega.com/blog/2010/08/09/add-events-on-google-calendar-on-android-froyo/).
- Use this http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/. Quoting from the project description on the website

> Written by Google, this library is a
>   flexible, efficient, and powerful Java
>   client library for accessing any
>   HTTP-based API's on the web. It is the
>   recommended library for accessing
>   Google API's based on REST or
>   JSON-RPC.

`

Answer (score 0):

Include these(Calendar-2.1,client 1.0,core 1.0) jar files from gdata api and include two external jar files in our application.. Those two files (guava-11.0.2 and jsr305 ) are available in deps folder of gdata

and this code for retrive events from calendar

Declare  globally your calendar id and password

you can reach to me on facebook by using this address on **facebook.com/rajivbawa22** for more tutorials

```
    String userName = "example@gmail.com"; // put here your gmail id 

String userPassword = "12345-example ";// put here your gmail password
```

but make sure you have account in gmail as well as in google calendar

try {

```
        CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("com.demo.calendar");

        myService.setUserCredentials(userName, userPassword);
        // Send the request and print the response
        URL feedUrl = new URL(
                "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/"+userName+"/private/full");
        // "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/owncalendars/full");
        Log.e("", "Calendar1========");
        CalendarFeed resultFeed = myService.getFeed(feedUrl,
                CalendarFeed.class);
        Log.e("", "Calendar2*********" + resultFeed);
        for (int i = 0; i < resultFeed.getEntries().size(); i++) {

            Log.e("", "========" + resultFeed.getEntries().size());

            CalendarEntry entry = resultFeed.getEntries().get(i);

            Log.e("", "**********" + entry.getTitle().getPlainText());

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

see result in logs and give yours feedbacks